# How much time Apple provides for resubmission of an application after rejecting an iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

The question makes it clear.I had submitted an iOS app to app store which was rejected.How much time I might get for resubmission of the application?

Comment: Do you have a binary that you want to resubmit now but can't? Or do you want to resubmit your binary later and want to know how much time you  are allowed to wait before resubmitting your app?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking for how much time you should wait before you can resubmit you app, then there is no such delay. You should be able to resubmit your app now.

If you are asking for how much time you are allowed to wait before resubmitting your app, then  there is no such delay too. Apple will not remove your app after it was rejected for the first time. (This is in opposition to Apple removing your app if you didn't submit a binary at all and for a few months and are only trying to squat an app name).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you can't upload another version now?

Click ready to upload binary and submit another one

Comment: The thing is that I have registered an app with a particular name which I don't want to loose.But after the period of 4 months after creation of app,Apple deletes the app and makes the name available to other developers.So I uploaded 'dummy build' and rejected it.How much time I will now get to complete my development?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such a rules to submit your app after a such time.
You can directly resubmit your any time after rejection. No such waiting time.

Comment: That's correct.I can resubmit it just after rejection also but do apple have some maximum limit for the time for which the app can be in 'Rejected' state?